Invitees meeting availability
I'm looking to create an email that lists all team member meeting availability that are shared using the team members listed in a meeting draft under attendees. If anyone is busy the time should not be listed. Basically taking all the suggested times from the scheduling assistant.
In a format such as:
10/21/24 9 am - 10 am, 2:30 pm - 3 pm
The code populates an email with times (wrong format) such as
Suggested meeting times: 
10/22/2024 (09:00 AM) 
10/22/2024 (09:30 AM) 
10/22/2024 (10:00 AM) 
10/22/2024 (10:30 AM) 
10/22/2024 (11:00 AM) 
10/22/2024 (11:30 AM) 
10/22/2024 (12:00 PM) 
10/22/2024 (12:30 PM) 

The times are incorrect. Not all members are available during those times.
Sub GetSharedFreeTimeWithStrictCheck()
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objAddressEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim objEmail As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim strAvailability As String
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim strFreeBusy As String
    Dim recipientResolved As Boolean
    Dim TimeSlotStart As Date
    Dim TimeSlotEnd As Date
    Dim slot As Integer
    Dim commonFreeTimes() As Boolean
    Dim actualSlots As Integer
    Dim firstRun As Boolean
    Dim WorkingHoursStart As Double
    Dim WorkingHoursEnd As Double
    Dim inFreeBlock As Boolean
    Dim blockStart As Date
    Dim currentDate As String
    
    ' Define the working hours (9 AM to 5 PM)
    WorkingHoursStart = 9 / 24 ' 9 AM as a fraction of a day
    WorkingHoursEnd = 17 / 24 ' 5 PM as a fraction of a day
    
    ' Ensure that the current item is a calendar invite (meeting request)
    If TypeOf Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then
        Set objAppt = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        MsgBox "Please open a calendar invite (meeting request) to use this script."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the date range (next 7 days, excluding weekends)
    StartDate = Date
    EndDate = Date + 7
    
    ' Set up Namespace to access Outlook data
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Flag to track if we are processing the first attendee
    firstRun = True
    
    ' Loop through each recipient (attendee) in the calendar invite
    For Each objRecipient In objAppt.Recipients
        recipientResolved = False
        On Error Resume Next
        recipientResolved = objRecipient.Resolve
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the recipient was resolved, get free/busy information
        If recipientResolved Then
            Set objAddressEntry = objRecipient.AddressEntry
            
            ' Get free/busy information for the next 7 days (in 30-minute intervals)
            On Error Resume Next
            strFreeBusy = objAddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(StartDate, 30, True)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' Determine the actual number of slots from the free/busy string length
            actualSlots = Len(strFreeBusy)
            
            ' If we successfully retrieved the free/busy string, process it
            If actualSlots > 0 Then
                ' Initialize the commonFreeTimes array if this is the first attendee
                If firstRun Then
                    ReDim commonFreeTimes(1 To actualSlots)
                    For slot = 1 To actualSlots
                        commonFreeTimes(slot) = True ' Assume all slots are free initially
                    Next slot
                    firstRun = False ' Mark that the first run has completed
                End If
                
                ' Process the current attendee's free/busy string, filtering by working hours
                For slot = 1 To actualSlots
                    TimeSlotStart = StartDate + ((slot - 1) * (1 / 48)) ' Each slot is 30 minutes
                    
                    ' Only consider weekdays (exclude Saturday and Sunday)
                    If Weekday(TimeSlotStart, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
                        ' Only consider slots between 9 AM and 5 PM
                        If TimeSlotStart - Int(TimeSlotStart) >= WorkingHoursStart And       TimeSlotStart - Int(TimeSlotStart) < WorkingHoursEnd Then
                            ' If this attendee is NOT free in this slot, mark it as busy (False)
                            If Mid(strFreeBusy, slot, 1) <> "0" Then
                                commonFreeTimes(slot) = False
                            End If
                            
                            ' Strict condition: if the current block or the next block has a meeting, this block is busy
                            If slot < actualSlots Then
                                If Mid(strFreeBusy, slot + 1, 1) <> "0" Then
                                    commonFreeTimes(slot) = False ' Mark this slot as busy if the next slot is not free
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next slot
            End If
        End If
    Next objRecipient
    
    ' Create a new email draft to display common availability
    Set objEmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objEmail.Subject = "Shared Free Time for All Attendees (9 AM to 5 PM, Weekdays Only)"
    
    ' Initialize the email body
    strAvailability = "Shared free blocks (9 AM to 5 PM) for the next 7 days (excluding weekends):" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    
    ' Loop through the commonFreeTimes array and find slots where all attendees are free during working hours
    inFreeBlock = False ' Track if we are inside a free time block
    
    For slot = 1 To actualSlots
        TimeSlotStart = StartDate + ((slot - 1) * (1 / 48)) ' Each slot is 30 minutes
        
        ' Only consider weekdays and slots between 9 AM and 5 PM
        If Weekday(TimeSlotStart, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
            If TimeSlotStart - Int(TimeSlotStart) >= WorkingHoursStart And TimeSlotStart - Int(TimeSlotStart) < WorkingHoursEnd Then
                If commonFreeTimes(slot) Then
                    ' If not already in a free block, start one
                    If Not inFreeBlock Then
                        blockStart = TimeSlotStart
                        inFreeBlock = True
                        currentDate = Format(blockStart, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                    End If
                Else
                    ' If we're in a free block but this slot isn't free, close the block
                    If inFreeBlock Then
                        TimeSlotEnd = TimeSlotStart ' End the block at the previous slot
                        strAvailability = strAvailability & "o " & currentDate & ": " & Format(blockStart, "hh:mm AMPM") & " - " & Format(TimeSlotEnd, "hh:mm AMPM") & vbCrLf
                        inFreeBlock = False
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                ' If we've hit the end of the working day, close the block
                If inFreeBlock Then
                    TimeSlotEnd = Int(TimeSlotStart) + WorkingHoursEnd ' End the block at 5 PM
                    strAvailability = strAvailability & "o " & currentDate & ": " & Format(blockStart, "hh:mm AMPM") & " - " & Format(TimeSlotEnd, "hh:mm AMPM") & vbCrLf
                    inFreeBlock = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next slot
    
    ' If we end the loop and are still inside a free block, close it at 5 PM
    If inFreeBlock Then
        TimeSlotEnd = Int(TimeSlotStart) + WorkingHoursEnd ' End the block at 5 PM of the last free slot day
        strAvailability = strAvailability & "o " & currentDate & ": " & Format(blockStart, "hh:mm AMPM") & " - " & Format(TimeSlotEnd, "hh:mm AMPM") & vbCrLf
    End If
    
    ' If no common free time slots were found
    If Len(strAvailability) <= 100 Then
        strAvailability = strAvailability & "No common free time slots found for all attendees during working hours (9 AM to 5 PM) on weekdays."
    End If
    
    ' Set the email body to include the common availability information
    objEmail.Body = strAvailability
    
    ' Display the email (you can use .Send to send it automatically)
    objEmail.Display
    
    ' Clean up
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objAppt = Nothing
    Set objEmail = Nothing
End Sub


This seems to work for me - I refactored a bit to remove repeated work and simplify the flow/reduce the level of nesting.
Notes:

running this from Excel so using late binding
skipped your "strict" check since I'm not sure I followed that
seems to have daylight savings time problem when the time span retrieved covers a clock change like the upcoming on on Nov 3 (if you're in the US like me)

Option Explicit
 
Sub GetSharedFreeTimeWithStrictCheck()
    Const MinPerDay As Long = 1440
    Const SlotMins As Long = 30
    Dim olApp As Object, objNS As Object, objAppt As Object, objRecipient As Object
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim strFreeBusy As String
    Dim actualSlots As Long
    Dim firstRun As Boolean
    Dim inFreeBlock As Boolean, goodSlots() As Double, commonFreeTimes() As Boolean
    Dim blockStart, sep As String, slotLen As Double
    Dim currentDay As Date, slotDay, colFB As Collection, i As Long, fb, free As Boolean, s As String
    
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application") 'I'm running this from Excel....
    
    ' Ensure that the current item is a calendar invite (meeting request)
    Set objAppt = olApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If TypeName(objAppt) <> "AppointmentItem" Then Exit Sub
    
    StartDate = Date
    
    ' Loop through each recipient (attendee) in the calendar invite and
    '    collect the freebusy info where available
    Set colFB = New Collection
    For Each objRecipient In objAppt.Recipients
        strFreeBusy = RecipientFreeBusy(objRecipient, StartDate, SlotMins, True)
        If Len(strFreeBusy) > 0 Then colFB.Add strFreeBusy
        'what if not available?
    Next objRecipient
    
    If colFB.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no free/busy info!
    
    actualSlots = Len(colFB(1))   'how many slots for each recipient?
    ReDim commonFreeTimes(1 To actualSlots)
    'get an array of all acceptable start times (or zero if not acceptable)
    goodSlots = usableSlots(actualSlots, StartDate, SlotMins)
    firstRun = True         ' Flag to track if we are processing the first attendee
    For Each fb In colFB    ' check all returned busyFree
        For i = 1 To actualSlots
            If goodSlots(i) > 0 Then 'day/time is potentially OK?
                free = (Mid(fb, i, 1) = "0")
                If firstRun Then
                    commonFreeTimes(i) = free
                Else
                    If Not free Then commonFreeTimes(i) = False
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        firstRun = False
    Next fb
    
    s = ""
    currentDay = 0
    inFreeBlock = False
    slotLen = SlotMins / MinPerDay  'slot length as a fraction of a day
    'loop and list common free slots
    For i = 1 To actualSlots
        blockStart = goodSlots(i)
        If commonFreeTimes(i) Then   'free ?
            If Not inFreeBlock Then 'starting a new block?
                slotDay = Int(blockStart)  'are we in a new day?
                If slotDay <> currentDay Then
                    s = s & vbLf & Format(blockStart, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ":"
                    currentDay = slotDay
                    sep = "" 'clear comma separator
                End If
                s = s & sep & " " & Format(blockStart, "hh:nn am/pm") & "-"
                inFreeBlock = True
                sep = "," 'add comma for next slot if any
            End If
        Else
            If inFreeBlock Then
                'fixed here (`goodSlots(i)` was zero if outside 9am-4:30pm)
                s = s & Format(goodSlots(i - 1) + slotLen, "hh:nn am/pm")
                inFreeBlock = False
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'should never end this loop in a free block...
    
    Debug.Print s '<<< put this in an email....
    
End Sub

'Try to resolve the recipient and get their FreeBusy info
Function RecipientFreeBusy(oRecip As Object, fromWhen, IntervalMins As Long, detailed As Boolean) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If oRecip.Resolve Then
        RecipientFreeBusy = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy(fromWhen, IntervalMins, detailed)
    End If
End Function

'Fill an array of length `numSlots` with potential start times, beginning at `StartDate`
'  and using an interval of `SlotMins`
'Acceptable start times are 9am to (5pm-SlotMins), Mon-Fri
Function usableSlots(numSlots As Long, StartDate, SlotMins As Long) As Double()
    Const MinPerDay As Long = 1440
    Dim WorkingHoursStart As Double, WorkingHoursEnd As Double
    Dim i As Long, slotStart, rv() As Double, slotLen As Double
    ' Define the working hours (9 AM to 5 PM)
    WorkingHoursStart = 9 / 24 ' 9 AM as a fraction of a day
    WorkingHoursEnd = 17 / 24  ' 5 PM as a fraction of a day
    slotLen = SlotMins / MinPerDay
    ReDim rv(1 To numSlots)
    
    For i = 1 To numSlots
        slotStart = StartDate + (i - 1) * (1 / 48)
        If Weekday(slotStart, vbMonday) <= 5 Then
            If slotStart - Int(slotStart) >= WorkingHoursStart Then
                If slotStart - Int(slotStart) <= (WorkingHoursEnd - slotLen) Then
                    rv(i) = slotStart 'populate the slot start
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    usableSlots = rv
End Function


Thank you for your help I'm still running into issues though. For example im getting 22-Oct-2024: 12:00pm-02:00pm, 03:00pm-12:00am when only 4:30 pm - 5:00 pm is available and the availabilities are running past working hours (9am-5pm)

Are you using my exact code as posted?

I am. I can try again but I tried it a few times

I can take a look tomorrow.  I did make one edit just now in usable slots but that likely wasn't the problem.

Sounds good I will look into it more tomorrow as well I appreciate the help!

Fixed and OK for me now.  The bug was that non-zero date-times in goodSlots only run up to 4:30 and the next slot (5pm) was zero, so that was rendering as 12:00 when closing out the day.

This corrected the times but the times provided are still showing conflicts:
22-Oct-2024: 12:00 pm-02:00 pm, 03:00 pm-04:30 pm
23-Oct-2024: 12:00 pm-12:30 pm, 01:00 pm-05:00 pm
24-Oct-2024: 10:00 am-11:00 am, 12:00 pm-01:00 pm, 03:00 pm-05:00 pm
Real availability is
10/23 4:30-5
10/24  10-10:30, 3-3:30, 430-5
is there something that could be off on my end?

Are your users all in the same time zone as you?  I have no idea how Outlook reports FreeBusy if there are different time zones involved...   Also as noted watch out for daylight saving shift by 1 hour...

I verified a couple of groups of users on my setup and the macro output seems to match exactly what I'm seeing on the Outlook calendar...

Correct they are all in the same time zone. I've ran into this issue before while trying to work this out. I'm not sure what the issue could be. Maybe tentative meetings or something?

I've also tried to find a workaround to pull directly from the scheduling assistant suggested times but have been unsuccessful. To make sure I'm not doing something incorrect are you just putting attendees in the required line on a meeting draft?

After looking at it it is just pulling strictly my own availability none of the other members needed.

I'm just opening an existing meeting with multiple attendees, and running it on that.  If it's only pulling your availability you might need to step through RecipientFreeBusy and see exactly where it's failing.  Are the other recipients not resolved? Or is the problem with  GetFreeBusy (one previous post on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793369/outlook-getfreebusy-method-returns-error-message)?   Would be worth adding some code to flag when one or more recipients aren't returning free/busy.

Yeah you're correct it does work on existing invites but I can't get it to work for a draft invite which is what it's really needed for are there any workarounds? I debugged and it was just pulling a string for me.

Works for me with a draft invite....

Is there anything specific you're doing that I could be missing? I type each individual in the required attendees then run the macro from excel and it provides only my availability. Also showed the recipients were getting resolved and the macro was looking at them just not pulling any times

I think I'm just doing the same thing as you.  In the draft, after adding a recipient, do you see their availability fill in?

FYI here's something on handling DST when using GetFreeBusy  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566126/how-to-handle-daylight-saving-when-using-the-outlook-c-sharp-getfreebusy-api

Fill in over in the suggested meeting times? I do. I don't know doesn't make sense to me but I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to code so not sure.

Loop through each recipient is where the issue is coming in after putting some debugging code in. It tells me free/busy info not available for the attendee. All recipients are resolved and access is allowed to their calendar.

Have you tried the suggestion posted at my earlier link ("Try to use the online mode with Exchange instead of cached one") to resolve this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793369/outlook-getfreebusy-method-returns-error-message

I have... Still nothing

Sorry I have no idea.  @EugeneAstafiev - any ideas?
